# Google Apps Recovery Phone Number, what API?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-apps, google-admin-sdk

I need to add phonenumbers to the users "recovery phone".

Under Settings > Personal Info > I can add a recovery phone number.

I have tried adding numbers thrue the Admin SDK API.

```
 phones: [
        {
          "value": phoneValue,
          "type": 'mobile',
          "primary": true
        }
      ]
```

I can see that the number was added some were when i pull json data from the user:

```
"phones": [
    {
      "primary": true,
      "value": "0731577762",
      "type": "mobile"
    }
  ],
```

But it's not adding it to the recovery phone. Is there any API for this?

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't tell if such data should be in the Directory API or in a hypothetical Google+ Profile API.
Either way, this can't be changed by any existing API at this time.

Sorry for the bad news.

Answer (score 0):

function addUser(firstname,lastname,personalemail,supervisor,position,language,phone,streetaddress,citystatezip,birthday,xSTARTDATE){

```
    var now = new Date(xSTARTDATE);
    var hiredate = Utilities.formatDate(now,"MDT","yyyy-MM-dd");
    var formattedaddress = (streetaddress + "\n" + citystatezip);
      var passwordx = Utilities.getUuid();
    /**
     * Adds a new user to the domain, including only the required information. For
     * the full list of user fields, see the API's reference documentation:
     * @see https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/users/insert
     */
    
      var user = {
        primaryEmail: newemail ,
        name: {
          givenName: firstname,
          familyName: lastname
        },
//  SET THE CORRECT UNIT PATH
            orgUnitPath: '/',
            recoveryEmail: personalemail,
            recoveryPhone: '+1'+phone,
            addresses: [{
                     type: "home", 
                     formatted: formattedaddress
                     }],
            relations: [{
                     value: supervisor,
                     type: "manager"
                     }],
            phones: [{
                     value: phone,
                     type: "mobile"
                     }],
            organizations: [{
                     title: position,
                     primary: true,
                     customType: "",
                     description: "non-exempt"
                     }],

//CUSTOM SCHEMA WRITING
            customSchemas: { 
                   Employment: {  
                     Birthday: birthday, 
                     Hire: hiredate,
                     Language_of_Choice: language,}
                     },
            // Generate a random password string.
            password: passwordx
          };
          user = AdminDirectory.Users.insert(user);
        }
```